# Getting the properties of an element in d3 is not elegant

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Here is my code snippet:

I was trying to understand how you can get at the properties of a DOM object using d3. In this case after the object has returned an event. So for example how would I access the 'x1' attribute.

```
var svg = d3.select('svg')
  .append('polyline')
  .attr('x1', 20)
  .attr('y1', 100)
  .attr('x2', 100)
  .attr('y2', 100)
  .attr('points', "20,100 100,100 100,100 180,100")
  .attr('fill', 'none')
  .attr('stroke', palette.gray)
  .attr('marker-start', "url(#triangle)")
  .attr('marker-mid', "url(#triangle)")
  .attr('marker-end', "url(#triangle)")
  .on('click', function(){
        console.log('polyline click');
        console.log(this);            
  });
```

I used

1. console.log(this['x1']); -- returns 'undefined'
2. console.log(this.attr('x1'); -- TypeError: this.attr is not a function
3. console.log(this.property('attr'); -- TypeError: this.property is not a function

I finally found the solution was to use: `d3.select(this).attr("cx")`

What is '**this**'? If I print 'this' to the console I seem to get the DOM object back as

```
<polyline x1="20" y1="100" x2="100" y2="100" points="20,100 100,100 100,100 180,100" fill="none" stroke="#708284" marker-start="url(#triangle)" marker-mid="url(#triangle)" marker-end="url(#triangle)">
```

It seems a bit 'hacky' to have to select the element again. Have I missed a trick here?

Comment: You haven't missed anything.  `.attr` is a method on a d3 selection, so of course you have to select again.  It's a JavaScript convention that `this` should be the element on which the event happened.  JQuery, for instance, follows the same model. If you don't want to select do it the straight [javascript way](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp): `this.getAttribute('x1');`

Comment: WOAHH i used getAttribute() and I think my brain exploded(it worked). So 'this' is a standardized reference to an DOM element so can be accessed via javascript and JQUERY too?

Comment: Yes, `this` here is a standard [DOM element](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp).  You can then convert it  into a `d3` selection with `d3.select(this)` or if desired a jQuery object with `$(this)` or use it however you need.

Comment: You'll probably also find that `d3.select(this)` is equivalent to `svg` the way you currently have it. You're assigning the result of `.append` to `svg`, which will be the polyline.

Comment: Imran - if my answer helped you would you care to accept it? If not is there anything else you need more detail on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope you've not missed anything.

`this` is indeed the DOM element as you logged, the problem is that `attr()` is a D3 function, specifically on a d3.selection.

What you need to do is convert the DOM element to a selection so you can take advantage of the d3 helper functions. The way to do that is just as you had

`d3.select(this)`